# CalendarAgent continuous error generation in MacOS 10.12.4

Tags: macos, error, console

After upgrading to MacOS 10.12.4 today, I started getting tons of Error/Fault log message in the Console generated by the `CalendarAgent` process. 
Some of the errors are pasted below:

```
error: sql cached statement NSSQLiteStatement <0x7fae52e27ad0> on entity 'CalDAVError' with sql text 'SELECT t0.Z_ENT, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZCODE, t0.ZDOMAIN, t0.ZUSERINFO, t0.ZCHANGEREQUEST, t0.Z8_CHANGEREQUEST, t0.ZPRINCIPAL, t0.ZOPERATION, t0.ZPRINCIPAL1, t0.ZPUBLICATION, t0.ZSUBSCRIPTIONINFO FROM ZERROR t0 WHERE ( t0.ZPRINCIPAL IN (SELECT * FROM _Z_intarray0)  AND  t0.Z_ENT = ?) ' failed due to missing variable binding for (null) with expecting bindings (
    "<NSSQLBindVariable: 0x7fae52eed410>"
) but actual substitution variables {
    destinations = "{0x400072b <x-coredata://F6135326-AEE3-4C69-AD55-060EF81D21A6/CalDAVPrincipal/p16>}";
}

error: sql cached statement NSSQLiteStatement <0x7fae551cadc0> on entity 'Attachment' with sql text 'SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZATTACHMENTID, t0.ZCONTENTTYPE, t0.ZFILENAMEINCACHE, t0.ZFILENAMESUGGESTEDBYSERVER, t0.ZISAUTOARCHIVED, t0.ZISCACHED, t0.ZOMITSYNCRECORD, t0.ZPATHONDISKSTRING, t0.ZURLSTRING, t0.ZUUID, t0.ZITEM, t0.Z4_ITEM FROM ZATTACHMENT t0 WHERE  t0.ZITEM IN (SELECT * FROM _Z_intarray0)  ORDER BY t0.ZITEM' failed due to missing variable binding for (null) with expecting bindings (
) but actual substitution variables {
    destinations = "{0xd340030b <x-coredata://F6135326-AEE3-4C69-AD55-060EF81D21A6/Event/p845>, 0xf2c0030b <x-coredata://F6135326-AEE3-4C69-AD55-060EF81D21A6/Event/p971>}";
}
```

The number of errors generated within a few minutes is more than 6000!. What do you think the reason could be? 
If you think I need to add more details, please state in the comments.

Comment: Discovered same today.. researching it now. You found an answer?

Comment: @J.C.Matos no, not yet. I have tried to remove some of the calendar-related files to no avail. There are quite many other I get sporadically.

Comment: In 10.12 they completely revamped console and the logging subsystem. Unfort it is way too verbose now. If you're not actually experiencing a problem then it's probably safe to ignore.

Comment: @Hefewe1zen Yes, that is what I also suspect due to the fact that, as you stated, the number of errors generated are staggering. Other processes as well produce tons of error messages.

Comment: Is this problem still present or did you fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The possible problem is that database schema or some of database entries are incompatible with latest Calendar app. Or may be these entries are corrupted.

There are 2 possible solutions:

- fix db which is tricky.
- drop db - it's just cached data of your cloud accounts.

to do the 2nd option:

- stop Calendar App (`ctrl+q`), then
- open `~/Library/Calendars` and
- remove `Calendar Cache` files (you may just trash them)
- start Calendar App again.

You will need probably reactivate your calendar accounts.

To do so, open calendar app settings and choose desired accounts in accounts section

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions

Comment: Did I just get down voted for a correct answer because I was too concise? This is not rocket science...

Comment: I didn't downvote you (I only downvote when there's egregious errors) and I disagree (very emphatically) with the voter if that was the premise.  I will upvote to cancel it out; though you should consider rewriting/expanding to *explain* what you are doing and why.

Comment: @xtfer I am guessing your concise and to-the-point answer actually solved my problem :) So, thanks for that and do not worry about the downvotes. No matter how you try to abide by the Stackoverflow regulations, there will always be someone to downvote:)

Comment: Alas, makes no difference here, the problem recurs.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to remove the "accepted" tick from the answer because the problem has been recurring since.

Comment: This answer is missing the key steps to make this removal useful, the cache files are opened by `CalendarAgent` or `iTunes`.